# how to show and return zero for data that doesn't appear?

Tags: mysql, sql

Can you help me with some `Queries`? I have two kind of table for `voting` which are [choices table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftuRx.png) and [submit table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH8AH.png), but there is one more table named [topic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsOwq.png) that related to that both tables. In short I need to get total vote from the [submit table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH8AH.png) for each choices that how many does it appears in that `submit table`, even if it is doesn't appear so it will return zero.

I have some Queries (kind of a hardcode) that I've tried, it does returns the right voting count but not for the choices that doesn't appear.

> ```
> SELECT vote_choices.name, vote_choice_submit.created_at,
> SUM(CASE WHEN `name` = 'Doe Jhons' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
> SUM(CASE WHEN `name` = 'Doe Jhonson' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
> SUM(CASE WHEN `name` = 'Doe Doe' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
> AS 'total_vote'
> FROM vote_choice_submit
> INNER JOIN vote_choices ON vote_choice_submit.vote_choice_id=vote_choices.choice_id
> GROUP by name
> ORDER by created_at DESC;
> ```

Let's say that `Doe Doe` doesn't exist in the `submit table` so I want it to show zero votes. But yet it doesn't appear on the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZF0HK.png).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question and post table data sample in textual form instead of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were using INNER JOIN, so that was the issue

```
SELECT vc.name, count(vcs.created_at) AS 'total_vote'
FROM vote_choices vc
LEFT OUTER JOIN vote_choice_submit vcs ON vcs.vote_choice_id = vc.choice_id
GROUP by vc.name
```

If you want to display created_at as well from vote_choice_submit, let me know if you want distinct values for each entry in vote_choice_submit or min/max. The query would need to be rewritten for that.

Comment: THANKS!! IT WORKS!! I'll let you know if  I actually need to display created_at.. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please accept this as answer, if it helped you?